# Call Java Script function if $POST or cookie is empty?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, post, cookies

I want to call a java script function called `expandRegisterForm()` if those conditions apply:

```
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        //call expandRegisterForm()
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        //call expandRegisterForm()
    }


    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        //call expandRegisterForm()
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_address_1'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_address_1'] ) ) {
        //call expandRegisterForm()
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_postcode'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_postcode'] ) ) {
        //call expandRegisterForm()
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_city'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_city'] ) ) {
        //call expandRegisterForm()
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_state'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_state'] ) ) {
        //call expandRegisterForm()
    }
```

This JS function expands the register formular. And this should only be expanded if there is something not entered. My question now is, how can I call this JS function?

I already tried this code in the header.php and the function.php with those both variations of calling a JS function:

1. `echo <script>expandRegisterForm()</script>;`
2. `?><script>expandRegisterForm();</script><?php`

None of them are working. Could it be because I inserted the code in the header.php and function.php?

Should I maybe insert the code somewhere else? If yes, where? I have a wordpress site just to know.

My second thought is that I could do it with a cookie. If a user presses a button, I set a cookie with an 1 hour flow time. And if the cookie is set, I call the `expandRegisterForm()` JS function. But same here. How and where do I call the function?

Would be very happy about help!
Kind regards

Comment: if you want to run the script if fields are missing then you should be checking for empty fields in javascript and running the function before the form is submitted.  If you want to redisplay the form after submission then you will need to either use a php function to display the additional form fields (probably the better choice) or add the function call to a document.ready equivalent on the page.

Comment: The page reloads if there is something missing on the form. So, I cannot chagne the plugin. This is the reason why I want to call this function, if the page gets reloaded and the conditions above apply. But where do I have to insert the JS code for calling the function?

Answer (score 0):

Since you called `expandRegisterForm`on header.php, its being called too soon before the form that this function is supposed to expand is even created in the DOM.
May be you can try this. On header.php

```
 $expand_form = false;
if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
    $expand_form = true;
}
...
```

On footer.php

```
if($expand_form ==true)
{
    echo "<script>expandRegisterForm()</script>";
}
```

I have to point out though that this is not really the best way to do this. Ideally you would want to validate the fields with javascript before its submitted.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't cross the streams!**

WordPress best practice, you should be using [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) for this:

In your `functions.php`:

```
// check for required vars. If any are missing, 'true' will be assigned
$expand_form_var = ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) )
               || ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) )
               || ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) )
               || ( isset( $_POST['billing_address_1'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_address_1'] ) )
               || ( isset( $_POST['billing_postcode'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_postcode'] ) )
               || ( isset( $_POST['billing_city'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_city'] ) )
               || ( isset( $_POST['billing_state'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_state'] ) )
    ? true
    : false;


// Register the script the normal WordPress way
wp_register_script( 'my_theme_script', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Add the variable to an array, where the arbitrary key name will be used to call the var in the JS script
$php_to_js_vars = array(
    'expand_form_key' => $expand_form_var,
);

// Localize the script to make the variable available in the JS script
wp_localize_script( 
    'my_theme_script', // you need to pass in script handle used in 'wp_register_script' to make the var available in it.
    'php_checks', // this is an arbitrary name that will be used to call the object in the localized JS
    $php_to_js_vars // an array of variables to pass to localize in the JS script. These will be made available using dot annotation (object.property) in the Js file
);

// finally enqueue the previously registered script using the handle you defined in the top function
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_theme_script' );
```

and then in `path/to/myscript.js` you would use it like this:

```
// 'php_checks' is the object name defined in the 'wp_localize_script' function. 'expand_form_key' was the key from the PHP array where the required variable was assigned.
if ( php_checks.expand_form_key === true )
    expandRegisterForm();
```

This way, all your PHP var logic is cleanly handled in PHP and the JS only needs the conditional before running the code.

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: @Ignacio I think I see where you mean now. Updating :)